# PGFPlots - no markers in Scatter Plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm using this code in a document:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[
    xlabel=$a$,
    ylabel=$b$,
]
\addplot[blue,mark=*,mark options={fill=blue},nodes near coords,only marks,
   point meta=explicit symbolic,
   visualization depends on={value \thisrow{anchor}\as\myanchor},
   every node near coord/.append style={anchor=\myanchor}
] table[meta=label] {
x y label anchor
100 152 {Long label 1} south
200 180 {Long label 2} east
110 150 {Long label 3} west
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Everything is perfect, but now I want to know how I erase the circles and stay with the labels?

Comment: Replace `mark=*` with `no marks`?

Comment: @HenriMenke, I think you mean `mark=*` should be replaced with `no markers`, right? (There is no key/style called `no marks`...). In addition to that you (Rafael) should also remove `mark options={fill=blue}` and especially `only marks`, because that is the opposite the style `no markers`.  If the comments helped to answer your question please let us know by commenting here or by editing your question, so we can close it as solved.

Comment: @StefanPinnow There is a style in `tikz` called `no marks`, and that works here as well. (`no marks` is also used once in an example in the `pgfplots` manual actually, though that might be a mistake.)

Comment: @HenriMenke, ok, didn't know that. Regarding the PGFPlots manual: Yep, I also found that and thought, that that is a mistake and have written [a bug report](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/131/) for that. ;)

Comment: @StefanPinnow Henri didn't write that last comment, but when he sees this he can probably just write up an answer right away.

Comment: @TorbjørnT., of course that comment was meant for you ...

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I discussed the option naming in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Simply replace all the mark related stuff by `no marks`.

*N.B.:* Actually, `pgfplots` does not have an option called `no marks` but it is `no markers` there.  The option `no marks` is inherited from TikZ.  To me this is counter-intuitive because the natural opposite of `only marks` should be `no marks` and not `no markers`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
  \begin{axis}[
    xlabel=$a$,
    ylabel=$b$,
    ]
    \addplot[blue,no marks,nodes near coords,only marks,
    point meta=explicit symbolic,
    visualization depends on={value \thisrow{anchor}\as\myanchor},
    every node near coord/.append style={anchor=\myanchor}
    ] table[meta=label] {
      x y label anchor
      100 152 {Long label 1} south
      200 180 {Long label 2} east
      110 150 {Long label 3} west
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]